# Select rows of the multi-level index data frame with index values equal to columns in another data frame in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, select

Having two data frames with the multi-level indices in one present as columns in the other, the idea is to select those rows from the first where the index values are the same as the corresponding column values.

Example

Having the following two data frames `df1` and `df2`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'i1': ['a1', 'a2', 'a3'], 'i2': ['b1', 'b2', 'b3'], 'c': [1, 2, 3]})
df1 = df1.set_index(['i1', 'i2'])

       c
i1 i2   
a1 b1  1
a2 b2  2
a3 b3  3


df2 = pd.DataFrame({'i1': ['a1', 'a3'], 'i2': ['b1', 'b3']})

   i1  i2
0  a1  b1
1  a3  b3
```

Select those rows of `df1` which index values `i1` and `i2` have the same values as the columns `i1` and `i12` in `df2` resulting in:

```
       c
i1 i2   
a1 b1  1
a3 b3  3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.isin.html) with `MultiIndex`:

```
df = df1[df1.index.isin(df2.set_index(['i1','i2']).index)]
```

Alternative:

```
df = df1[df1.index.isin(pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df2['i1'], df2['i2']]))]
```

Or use `merge`, `join` - but necessary reset and set index:

```
df = df1.reset_index().merge(df2).set_index(['i1', 'i2'])
df = df2.join(df1, on=['i1', 'i2'], how='inner').set_index(['i1', 'i2'])
```

---

```
print (df)
       c
i1 i2   
a1 b1  1
a3 b3  3
```